# list of functions Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, reference

I have a list of patterns:

```
    patterns_trees = [response.css("#Header").xpath("//a/img/@src"), 
                      response.css("#HEADER").xpath("//a/img/@src"),
                      response.xpath("//header//a/img/@src"),
                      response.xpath("//a[@href='"+response.url+'/'+"']/img/@src"),
                      response.xpath("//a[@href='/']/img/@src")
                      ]
```

After I traverse it and find the right pattern I have to send the pattern as an argument to a callback function

```
for pattern_tree in patterns_trees:
...
    pattern_response = scrapy.Request(...,..., meta={"pattern_tree": pattern_tree.extract_first()})
```

By doing this I get the value of the regex not the pattern

**THINGS I TRIED:**

I tried isolating the patterns in a separate class but still I have the problem that I can not store them as pattern but as values.

I tried to save them as strings and maybe I can make it work but

**What is the most efficient way of storing list of functions**

**UPDATE: Possible solution but too hardcoded and it's too problematic when I want to add more patterns:**

```
def patter_0(response):
    response.css("#Header").xpath("//a/img/@src")    
def patter_1(response):
    response.css("#HEADER").xpath("//a/img/@src")
.....
class patternTrees:
    patterns = [patter_0,...,patter_n]

    def length_patterns(self):
        return len(patterns)
```

Comment: Should a specific pattern be related to a specific function?

Comment: In `meta` you're sending `.extract_first()`, the brackets cause it to execute. Try sending `.extract_first` instead (without brackets) to send the actual function.

Comment: @Magnus yes I want to have a specific function for each pattern, so that I can send arguments to it

Comment: @Swier no, that is not the problem, with or without that function `pattern_tree` is already a computed result

Comment: You can use the object `response` is an instance of to access its methods. For strings you can do this: `[str.upper, str.lower][0]('test')` -> `'TEST'`

Comment: Can you suggest me further readings on that ?

Comment: @Hartun have a look at this post: https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to consider reformatting your list of operations, then this is a somewhat neat solution. I've changed the list of operations to a list of tuples. Each tuple contains (a ref to) the appropriate function, and another tuple consisting of arguments.

It's fairly easy to add new operations to the list: just specify what function to use, and the appropriate arguments.

If you want to use the result from one operation as an argument in the next: You will have to return the value from *execute()* and process it in the *for loop*.

I've replaced the calls to *response* with *prints()* so that you can test it easily.

```
def response_css_ARG_xpath_ARG(args):
    return "response.css(\"%s\").xpath(\"%s\")" % (args[0],args[1])
    #return response.css(args[0]).xpath(args[1])

def response_xpath_ARG(arg):
    return "return respons.xpath(\"%s\")" % (arg)
    #return response.xpath(arg)

def execute(function, args):
    response = function(args)
    # do whatever with response
    return response 

response_url = "https://whatever.com"


patterns_trees = [(response_css_ARG_xpath_ARG, ("#Header", "//a/img/@src")), 
                  (response_css_ARG_xpath_ARG, ("#HEADER", "//a/img/@src")),
                  (response_xpath_ARG, ("//header//a/img/@src")),
                  (response_xpath_ARG, ("//a[@href='"+response_url+"/"+"']/img/@src")),
                  (response_xpath_ARG, ("//a[@href='/']/img/@src"))]

for pattern_tree in patterns_trees:
    print(execute(pattern_tree[0], pattern_tree[1]))
```

Note that *execute()* can be omitted! Depending on if you need to process the result or not. Without the executioner, you may just call the function directly from the loop:

```
for pattern_tree in patterns_trees:
    print(pattern_tree[0](pattern_tree[1]))
```

Comment: maybe that is the most clever way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but could you make your list a list of lambda functions like so:

```
patterns_trees = [
    lambda response : response.css("#Header").xpath("//a/img/@src"),
    ...
]
```

And then, in your loop:

```
for pattern_tree in patterns_trees:
    intermediate_response = scrapy.Request(...)  # without meta kwarg
    pattern_response = pattern_tree(intermediate_response)
```

Or does leaving the `meta` away have an impact on the `response` object?